# How to search for all lines that start with a pattern, but then don't have another following pattern?

Tags: regex, visual-studio, regex-negation

The selection I want is:

```
pushbutton.*
```

but I don't want any selection that includes 'justify_cell' within it

```
(?!.*justify_cell)
```

I can get select all lines that don't include 'justify_cell'

```
^(?!.*justify_cell).*$
```

But I cannot seem to hit on a way to select from pushbutton to end of line if it doesn't include 'justify_cell'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was being a dummy - but the basic answer seems to be:

```
^(?!.*justify_cell).*(pushbutton.*)$
```

Comment: `^(?!.*justify_cell.*).*(pushbutton.*)$` to match grp from pushbutton forward ?

Comment: yes, in fact, updated my own answer to include your suggestion :)